# Link Excel Office.js with Powershell Dataverse (PSDataverse)

Tags: powershell, office365, powerapps, dataverse

I have an excel instance in which I am authenticated and able to access Dataverse.  I would like to be able to use the credentials from my excel instance to be able to run the PSDataverse script to load a csv to Dataverse from my computer.  Is this possible ?

```
Connect-Dataverse "authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/authorize;clientid=<client-id>;clientsecret=<client-secret>;resource=https://<environment>.crm4.dynamics.com/"
Import-Csv "Account.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    @{ Uri = "account", Method= "PATCH", Value = @{
        name = $_.AccountName,
        overridencreatedon = $_.CreationDate,
        ...}}} | ConvertTo-Json | Send-DataverseOperation
```

Answer (score 0):

PSDataverse is an extension to PowerShell; its "home" page is here: https://bycode.dev/2022/07/13/introducing-psdataverse-powershells-new-super-power/

It is not Microsoft Supported, so should probably be used with caution

The GIT page is more useful https://github.com/rezanid/PSDataverse

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no secure way to pass the authentication context from Excel to PowerShell. But there is an easier way for what you want to do.

## Solution 1

You just need to either export the Excel sheet into CSV format which can be done in Excel, then you just need to run your script to load the data to Power Platform. PSDataverse supports "device" authentication (explained in the [Github repository](https://github.com/rezanid/PSDataverse#connecting-to-dataverse)) that you can use without even hardcoding your credentials.

## Solution 2

If you don't want to convert your Excel sheet to CSV, you might be able to use [Import-Excel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) to load data directly from Excel.